# Не могу обновить pictureBox из другого потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Есть ф-ция, которая зеркально отображает содержимое picturebox (которое там из Bitmap bit). Все работает ок. Если запустить, то через несколько секунд картинка меняется на отображенную по горизонтали. Но! Мне надо сделать так, чтобы юзер видел не только начальный и конечный результат, а видел "плавное перетекание пикселей". Если делать без потоков и писать `pictureBox1.Refresh()`, то все ок. Если исп потоки, запускать ф-цию в новом, то пишет, что нельзя юзать pictureBox1 в потоке, отличном от того, в котором компонент создан. Я уже пытался исп события, но результат аналогичен.
Очень прошу вас помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нельзя юзать pictureBox1 в потоке отличном от того, в котором компонент создан

Это так. Все обращения к UI-компонентам из другого потока должны перенаправляться в UI-поток. Это можно сделать, используя функцию [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx). Проверить, нужно ли в данный момент использовать `Invoke`, можно с помощью свойства [`InvokeRequired`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx). В итоге некая функция для работы с контролом из другого потока выглядит часто так:

```
void UpdateControl()
{
    if (myControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myControl.Invoke(UpdateControl); // вызываем эту же функцию обновления состояния, но уже в UI-потоке
    }
    else
    {
        // код обновления состояния контрола
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к элементам управления из потоков необходимо производить через Invoke.

Пример:

```
Label1.Invoke(new myDelegate(myMethod), new Object[] {1,
   "This is the string"});
```